# Get previous workday (weekday) from today with Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

Every day I run script which downloads couple of files by ftp to lets say **C:\files\ directory** with names like:

> ```
> sampl_position_20220714
> sampl_position_20220715 
> sample1_newposition_20220715
> ```
>
> etc.

All files comes with timestamp and files generating only at workdays (all days except Saturday and Sunday).
I need to get file which starts with **sampl_position_** and **last_workday** from today

I know how to get next workday:

```
(date)+"$(1+$(@(1,2-eq7-(date).dayofweek)))"
```

But failed to get last workday
Spent couple of days trying to find solution but still couldnt get what I want (

Maybe someone could help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Get the most recent weekday preceding today's date
# (Mon-Fri, not holiday-aware)
$mostRecentWeekDay = 
  ($dt = Get-Date).AddDays(
    $(switch ($dt.DayOfWeek) { 'Monday' { -3 } 'Sunday' { -2 } default { -1 } })
  )

# Synthesize the file name
'sampl_position_{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $mostRecentWeekday
```

Note: Despite the use of *strings* (e.g, `'Monday'`), this solution is *not* culture-dependent. Because `.DayOfWeek` is of type [`[System.DayOfWeek]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DayOfWeek), a comparison value of, say, `'Monday'`, is implicitly interpreted as the symbolic name of the  equivalent enumeration value, `[System.DayOfWeek]::Monday`. You're free to use the latter instead, but it is obviously more verbose.

Comment: Wow so fast!!! :)
WOrks like a charm! Thank you very much, you savd another weeks of trying to get same result! 
Hav a nice day mate!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @РоманРослый; my pleasure. Your own solution for getting the _next_ workday is impressively short, but a bit mind-bending.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer that doesn't rely on names (names are language specific I think? sorry, monolingual here).

```
if(($date.DayOfWeek-1) -gt 0){$date.AddDays(-1)}else{$date.AddDays(-3-($Date.DayOfWeek-1))}
```

This checks to see if the previous day's day of week value is 1 or greater, if not jump back 3 days offset by the remaining days in the weekend from the day before. That sounds complicated, but I think I'm just explaining it poorly.

Comment: While it may seem that way, there is _no_ (human) language / culture issue here: in the solution in my answer, strings such as `'Monday'` are implicitly converted to - culture-invariant - _enum_ values; I've added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: OK, good to know that enums are not culture specific. I had assumed that in another culture it would look for `[System.DayOfWeek]::Lunes` or something like that. Strange that all cultures accept english names for the day of the week.

Comment: `enum` values are identifiers, just like class names, property names, method names, and as such have fixed, culture-invariant names. Culture-sensitivity only comes into play when you generate _for-display_ string representations, such as `Get-Date -Format dddd`